# Test selection help for ages in Haberman's Cancer Survival Data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, biostatistics

I recently completed Udacity's Inferential Statistics Introductory course and I selected Haberman's Survival Data Set as my final project's data set (please google the data set as I cannot add more than one link)

**My Question**

Does the following test selection make sense for this data?

**Data Description**

Contains Ages, Year of Operation, Survived within 5 years? (Yes/No) and # of Positive Auxiliary Nodes.

**Basic analysis on Ages**

```
N = 360
Min, Max Ages = [30, 83] 
Mean Age = 52.46 years
Median Age = 52
Standard Deviation = 11.19
```

**Hypothesis**

*Research Question*: Does age have an affect on post-op 5 year morality, regardless of number of detected auxiliary nodes?

*Ho*: Variable A and B are independent, i.e. age and 5 year mortality are independent.

*Ha*: Variable A and B are dependent, i.e. age has some affect on 5 year mortality.

**Data Setup**

Data was setup as a frequency table:

- Rows: Age Ranges (30 to 84), at 5 year intervals
- Column 1: Yes (Observed)
- Column 2: No (Observed)

where Yes and No are "did they survive" frequencies summing to n (306).

I also added in the "expected frequency" using the formula
    (row total * column total) / n

You can [see the table here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqeOA.png)

**Test Selection**

I consider both the variables to be categorical; age and Survival Yes/No as categorical. **I have a feeling this could be wrong.**

Thus, because of the above I used the **Chi Squire Test for Independence.**

**Results**

Using Python's chi-square function under SciPy:

```
chi-squared = 14.26
p = 0.85
```

*p value is greater than 0.05, so we retain our null hypothesis. We can say Age and post op 5 year survivability are independent.*

I would really appreciate if my thinking is in order, if not, how do we assess, "does age affect post-op 5 year mortality rates".

I have learnt that categorizing continuous data is called Dichotomizing.

Lastly, would it be sensible to **compare four distributions**, as in Histogram of Yes (Observed) vs Histogram of Yes (Expected) and the same for "No"?